# RxJava operators

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm learn rxjava using this article: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/
and can't reproduce first example of this article
I did next:

```
Observable<List<String>> query(String text); //Gradle: error: missing method body, or declare abstract

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    query.subscribe(urls -> {    //Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable query
        for (String url : urls) {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    });

}
```

But I have an errors, which I added as comments
What I did wrong?

Comment: this looks like java8. I don't think you can use java8 on android yet.

Comment: Correct! Android does support java7 with some limitations only

Comment: Thank you. You right. I forget it

Comment: You can take a look at RetroLambda if you want to use lambdas - https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: Dan mentions this in Part 1: "Finally, let's use Java 8 lambdas to get rid of that ugly Action1 code. ... If you're on Android (and thus can't use Java 8), I highly recommend using retrolambda; it will cut down on the verbosity of your code immensely."

Comment: @alexlodoss is your problem is solved? Can you please share a sample code here. I also want to use lamda expression in my android ADT application

Comment: @muhammadusmankhan    Observable<List<String>> query(String text) { return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url_null", "url0")); }

Comment: @alexlodoss can you please give me any sample application/tutorial application which uses such feature. I want to use it in my code, and i found not very stuff or sample application which uses this. Please share a link of any sample application like on github or any other place. I will be very thankful to you for this regard.

Comment: @muhammadusmankhan here is an [app](http://dropmefiles.com/qxsE2) which i did using article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 8 lambdas aside, most of the people here are missing the fact that your code won't compile regardless RetroLambda or any other nifty tool that you find somewhere to work around the *missed lambda feature in Android*...

So, take a close look to your code, you even had added some comments to the snippet which are actually explaining you why you are having some compilation errors:

**1 You have a method with an empty body**:

```
Observable<List<String>> query(String text);
```

So, add a method body to it and problem solved. What do you want to do? You don't know yet? Then add a dummy or empty body and work that out later:

```
Observable<List<String>> query(String text) {
  return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("url1", "url2"));
}
```

**2 There is no `query` variable at all in your code**. What you've got is a `query` method, and the syntax to use methods requires you to use braces:

```
query("whatever").subscribe(urls -> {
        for (String url : urls) {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    });
```

Now add the RetroLambda or use anonymous classes and you are done. Bear in mind that nothing out of this will add much functionality to your code but will solve just those compilation errors. Now ask yourself what do you want to do in your query method and carry on.

**Note**: An Observable object is a stream of data, which basically means that you might get zero elements, one element, or many; all of them instances of the specified type. So your code seems to expect a stream of lists of strings, if what you really want is a stream of strings, then replace `Observable<List<String>>` for `Observable<String>`.

Answer (score 3):

By `Gradle: error:` you mean compilation error? You should probably put parentheses between `query` and `.subscribe(urls -> {` as this is not a variable or class filed but method instead, so you should call it to get `Observable` to subscribe to.

Well, also you need to implement query method to return `Observable`, for example like this:

```java
private Observable<String> query() {

    return Observable.just("one", "two", "three");

}
```

You'll get another build error because of Java 8 but as already mentioned in comments you can easily use  retrolamda with gradle to fix the problem. Otherwise you can use Android Studio quick fixes to convert java 8 lambdas into java 6 anonymous classes.